# Why does `ann = F` not work when plotting with `as.factor` in R?

Tags: r, plot, r-factor

I am plotting a continuous variable against a factor using `plot()` in R (see example below).  I do not want the labels on the axes.  Without the `as.factor` call in the formula `ann = F` suppresses the printing of the labels but it doesn't work with `as.factor` in the formula.

Why is this?

Thank you.

```
# example for SO
# example data 
x <- sample(1:100, 10)
y <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))

# ann = F doesn't work here
plot(x ~ as.factor(y), ann = F)

# ann = F does work here
plot(x ~ y, ann = F)
```

Comment: I would say that this warrants a "wishlist" e-mail to the r developers' list ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be caused by `plot.formula` because it works if you specify `x` and `y` separately:

```
plot(as.factor(y), x, ann=FALSE)
```

UPDATE:

Confirmation that it's in `graphics:::plot.formula`.  The line that calls `plot` explicitly sets `ylab` and `xlab` (`funname` is `"plot"` and `dots` = `list(ann=FALSE)`):

```
do.call(funname, c(list(mf[[i]], y, ylab = yl, xlab = xl), dots))
```

Comment: @ Joshua: When I insert a debugging print(dots) statement just before that line, I get: $ann
[1] FALSE. So plot.factor is the function that removes the ann=FALSE

Comment: Try: graphics:::plot.factor(as.factor(y), x, ann=FALSE) ... FAILS.

Comment: @Dwin: I didn't suggest `ann=FALSE` was removed.  It's over-ridden by explicitly setting `ylab` and `xlab`.  `graphics:::plot.factor(as.factor(y), x, ann=FALSE)` doesn't label either axis for me; `graphics:::plot.factor(as.factor(y), x)` doesn't label them either.

Comment: Weird. I get "1" and '2" below the ticks in both instances. MacOSX 10.5.8,R 2.13.0 beta (2011-04-04 r55296)

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu 64-bit and WinXP 32-bit, both R-2.13.0. Maybe a quartz issue?

Answer (score 2):

The dispatching system sends the non-working one to plot.factor, which then sends it to boxplot, which doesn't have an ann= argument, while the "working " one goes to plot.data.frame, which goes to plot.default eventually, which does honor the ann= argument. To suppress the naming. use:

plot(x ~ as.factor(y), names = rep("", 2))

Comment: Given my answer, I don't think it's in `graphics:::plot.factor` and `boxplot` respects `ann`: `boxplot(x ~ as.factor(y), ann=FALSE)`.